# Qt QTcpSocket streaming

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, qiodevice, qdatastream

My application sent object to the server via `QTcpSocket`.

Client:

```
void client::sendFile(QString path)
{
    QFile toSend(path);
    QByteArray rawFile;
    rawFile = toSend.readAll();

    QDataStream out(cl);
    out >> rawFile;
}
```

Server:

```
void server::handleClient()
{
    QTcpSocket *curCl = srv->nextPendingConnection();
    QByteArray z;
    QDataStream in(curCl);
    in >> z;

    QFile qwe("test.dat");
    qwe.write(z);
    qwe.close();
}
```

The problem is that nothing happens, but debug console told me:

```
QIODevice::write: device not open
QIODevice::read: device not open
```

... but the `QDataStream` object doesn't allow me to set open mode up! :(
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QFile` + `QFile.write` (or `QFile.read`) requires `QFile.open`, see example:

Write:

```
QFile qwe("test.dat");
if(qwe.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
  qwe.write(z);
  qwe.close();
} else {
  qDebug() << "Error";
}
```

or

```
#include <QTextStream>

...

QFile qwe("test.dat");
if(qwe.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
   QTextStream out(&qwe);
   out << "This file is generated by Qt\n";
   qwe.close();
} else {
  qDebug() << "Error";
}
```

Read:

```
QFile toSend(path);
if(toSend.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {//Open "read file"
    QByteArray rawFile;
    rawFile = toSend.readAll();

    QDataStream out(cl);
    out >> rawFile;
    toSend.close();//close
}
```